# QGIS 3.x contour creation tutorial

Tags: qgis-3, contour, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-visualize-water-quality-data-in-qgis-3-from-points-to-raster-to-contour-lines-tutorial) so I have a method for creating contours in QGIS because I find the contours generated by the contour plugin a bit strange (very sharp edges and whatnot).

I can't get past the first stage of creating the raster using IDW interpolation.

I get the following error when I "Run as batch process":

> NameError: name 'QgsDoubleSpinBox' is not defined

I am using QGIS 3.6 Noosa

I'm wondering if anyone can successfully create the raster and how to do it? Can anyone successfully do the whole tutorial in 3.6 or whatever version they're using?

There is downloadable input files with the tutorial and so I downloaded them and I add the layer as a vector layer. I have tried using the .dbf, .shx and .shp but they all produced the same error for me.

I'm new to QGIS so I might be doing something wrong.

[Points to Raster to Contour Lines Tutorial](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-visualize-water-quality-data-in-qgis-3-from-points-to-raster-to-contour-lines-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have generated contours from a point based file using the Contour plugin, you may want to try using the Processing Toolbox, QGIS Vector Geometry "Smooth" routine.

Set your tolerances to what you can live with, and start with 5 iterations.
The routine will create a temporary layer which can be made permanent.

I do this quite frequently with Topographic Point survey data.
It takes a little bit of trial and error, but the routine is fast, and you can tailor the results to what you desire.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial [How to create contour line in QGIS 3](https://www.geodose.com/2018/05/how-to-create-contour-lines-in-qgis.html)

Comment: I have successfully used that method to create contours, but I am not happy with the output. It produces very angular contours. Might be better for terrain than for environmental chemical concentrations. I am looking for a solution that gets the IDW interpolation working. Basically wondering if anyone else has been able to do it successfully and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, Contouring is suitable for terrain interpolation. For environmental application spatial interpolation like IDW, Kriging, etc works better. If you have problem especially about how to do IDW interpolation in QGIS, take a look this tutorial [how to perform idw interpolation in QGIS](https://www.geodose.com/2019/03/spatial-interpolation-inverse-distance-weighting-idw.html). Hopefully it would help